# Error in document

Tags: errors, formatting

I am writing my first document in LaTeX, and I have the following error: [image: Error]

Quando para qualquer que seja $\varepsilon$ > 0 existe um $\delta$ > 0 tal que para todo \textit{x $\subset$ I} satisfazendo  $\vert$ x - a $\vert$ < $\delta$ vale $\vert$ f(x) - A$\vert$ < $\varepsilon$ Ou usando nota{\c c}{\~a} o simbolica, teremos: A \displaystyle{$\lim_${x $\to$ a} f(x)} $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall$ $\varepsilon$ > 0, $\exists$ $\delta$ > 0, $\forall$ $\subset$ I; 0 < $\vert$ x - a$\vert$ < $\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $\vert$ f(x) - A $\ver$ < $\varepsilon$}

Comment: @Bernard I'm in tilt :-((((

Comment: @Bernard I don't remember with all my heart what I had written. I am very tired for school reasons :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\begin{document}
Quando para qualquer que seja $\varepsilon > 0$ existe um $\delta > 0$ tal que
para todo $x\subset I$ satisfazendo $\vert x - a \vert < \delta$ vale $\vert f(x)
- A\vert < \varepsilon$ Ou usando nota{\c c}{\~a}o simbolica, teremos: A
$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0,
\ \exists\delta> 0,\ \forall\subset I; 0 < \vert x - a\vert <
\delta\Rightarrow\vert f(x) - A \vert < \varepsilon$
\end{document}
```

Your error was due to the fact that you used the `\displaystyle` command outside the Math mode. Also, you have used too many `$`'s in the wrong place.